# tar list files only

Tags: tar

Fun fact: If you use *Archive Manager* and extract a .tar.gz so that you have "Keep directory structure" unticked, you will get a *tarbomb*.

`tar -ztf` lists all the files and directories in a tar file.
Is there a way to list all the files in a tar file, **without** the directory structure?

Comment: You can get the 'tarbomb' effect with `tar xvzf my_tar.tar.gz --transform  's/.*\///'`. But unfortunately that doesn't change how it displays in a listing with `t` rather than `x`.

Comment: What bothers me is that even well structured archives can so easily be used to create weapons of mass extraction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see a way to do it from the man page, but you can always filter the results. The following assumes no newlines in your file names:

```
tar tzf your_archive | awk -F/ '{ if($NF != "") print $NF }'
```

**How it works**

By setting the field separator to `/`, the last field `awk` knows about (`$NF`) is either the file name if it's processing a file name or empty if it's processing a directory name (`tar` adds a trailing slash to directory names). So, we're basically telling `awk` to print the last field if it's not empty.

Comment: Pretty nice work with awk :)

Answer (score 8):

Utilizing Joseph R.'s suggestion one can use the regex `[^/]$` to `grep` for the files by looking for lines not ending with `/`.

`tar tzf archive.tar.gz | grep -e "[^/]$"`

Comment: That still outputs `foo/bar` as opposed to just `bar`. You want `grep -Eo '[^/]+$'` (with GNU grep).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas probably best to filter then extract for large tars: `tar tzf archive.tar.gz | grep -v '/$' | grep -o '[^/]*$` (no need for `-e`)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming none of the file names contain newlines:

```
tar -tf foo.tar | sed -e 's#.*/##' -e '\#.#!d'
```

The first sed command removes everything before the last `/` on a line, so that only the file name part is printed. The second command deletes the lines which are now empty, i.e. the lines that ended in a `/`, which are directories.

Comment: sed: -e expression #2, char 2: unknown command: `/'
and the sed syntax does not feel very.. intuitive

Comment: @EeroAaltonen I fixed the sed command. Indeed, the syntax is somewhat cryptic (I do include explanations in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

With `pax` (the POSIX command to read `tar` files):

```
pax -'s@.*/@@' < file.tar
```

(that lists all files regardless of their type, including directories).