# tar list full filename without directory

Tags: awk, grep, tar, zip, compression

I have a `tgz` file with the following file structure

```
- folder
    - subdir1
      - file1.txt
      - file2.text
    - subdir2
      - file1.txt
```

When i run `tar -tf folder.tgz`, it outputs the following:

```
folder/
folder/subdir1/
folder/subdir1/file1.txt
folder/subdir1/file2.txt
folder/subdir2/
folder/subdir2/file1.txt
```

How can i exclude directory names so that the outputted list is:

```
folder/subdir1/file1.txt
folder/subdir1/file2.txt
folder/subdir2/file1.txt
```

Comment: `tar -tf folder.tgz | grep -v /$`

Comment: @Bib pelase don't post answers in comments. That circumvents the site's quality control procedure since comments cannot be downvoted and also can discourage others from answering which results in the question left unanswered. Also note that your approach would fail if any of the paths contain newline characters.

Comment: @terdon, I've just checked, and yes it does catch new lines in file & directory names, since they are stored as, for example, `-rw-r--r-- b/users           0 2021-11-07 19:00 rr/hh\nll`, and that is how they are displayed. Thank you for asking...

Comment: @bib see, this is why we need answers: you are quite right that GNU `tar` seems to do this (nice!) but that isn't the case for other `tar` flavors (I just tested with busybox tar for example) and an answer could explain this and show the limitations.

Comment: I could always roll my own tar and have it convert new lines into pictures of chickens.

Comment: @Bib here is an implementation: `perl -MArchive::Tar -le 'for(Archive::Tar->new(shift)->get_files){print $_->name=~s/\n//gr if $_->type!=5}' archive.tgz`

Answer (score 5):

Use **awk**. Very well explained in this answer:
[tar list files only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101272/tar-list-files-only)

```
tar tzf your_archive | awk -F/ '$NF !=""'
```

Note that this assumes your `tar` implementation prints a literal `\n` if the paths contain newlines. GNU `tar` and `bsdtar` do this, but busybox `tar` and, presumably, others do not.

Comment: Note that this will fail if any of the paths contain newlines.

Comment: Have you actually tested that terdon, or are you just making an assumption?

Comment: @Bib both, actually. I was assuming (which is why I hadn't voted). But your comment made me test and see that GNU tar does indeed print literal `\n` but others don't which is why I just edited this answer again.

Comment: or even `...  |awk '/[^/]$/'`

Answer (score 5):

With `star` (from schily-tools):

```
star tzf file.tgz -find ! -type d
```

Answer (score 4):

If using GNU tar and your tar file isn't huge, you can use the [`--to-command` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Writing-to-an-External-Program) to run a command on each file:

```
% tar c folder | tar x --to-command 'printf "%s\n" "$TAR_REALNAME"'            
folder/subdir1/file1.txt
folder/subdir1/file2.txt
folder/subdir2/file1.txt
```

Currently the option only sends regular files to the command, but it's not hard to guard against directories being supported in the future, by using the `TAR_FILETYPE` variable set by tar:

```
% tar c folder | tar x --to-command '[ "$TAR_FILETYPE" != d ] && printf "%s\n" "$TAR_REALNAME"'
folder/subdir1/file1.txt
folder/subdir1/file2.txt
folder/subdir2/file1.txt
```